# Homogeneous transform of point clouds in camera coordinates to world coordinates using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, point-clouds, 3d-reconstruction, homogenous-transformation

I have camera calibration intrinsics and extrinsics (including rotations and translations, i.e. [rvecs and tvecs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d6a/group__aruco.html#gabefb98f7f2c74c98574fd50711c5349d), for a set of N camera poses, relative to a fixed ChArUco target.

Additionally, for every camera pose, I have a set of 3D coordinates ("point cloud") defined in the standard [OpenCV camera coordinate system](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga91018d80e2a93ade37539f01e6f07de5).

After a lot of reading, I would have thought that I need to first compute each camera pose relative to the ChArUCo board, by constructing a homogeneous transformation matrix like so in python:

```py
    # initialize 4x4 transform
    inverted_homogeneous_transform_matrix = np.zeros(shape=(4,4))
    inverted_homogeneous_transform_matrix[3,3] = 1.0

    # convert Rodrigues vector into Rodrigues matrix, and then invert it
    rotation_matrix = np.zeros(shape=(3,3))
    cv2.Rodrigues(rvecs, rotation_matrix)
    inverted_rotation = rotation_matrix.transpose()

    # add inverted rotation to transform
    inverted_homogeneous_transform_matrix[:3,:3] = inverted_rotation

    # compute inverted translation, e.g. see http://ksimek.github.io/2012/08/22/extrinsic/
    inverted_translation_vector = -inverted_rotation * tvecs
    inverted_transform_matrix[:3,3] = np.asarray(inverted_translation_vector).flatten()

    # x_coords, y_coords, z_coords are defined in camera coordinate system
    x_coords=np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5])
    y_coords=np.asarray([2,4,6,8,10])
    z_coords=np.asarray([3,6,9,12,15])

    homogeneous_ones = np.ones(len(x_coords))
    homogeneous_points = np.matrix([x_coords, y_coords, z_coords, homogeneous_ones])

    # perform the transformation
    transformed_points = inverted_transform_matrix * homogeneous_points

    # clean up to extract x,y,z values from matrix and save as 1D array
    x_coords = np.asarray(transformed_points[0,:]).flatten()
    y_coords = np.asarray(transformed_points[1,:]).flatten()
    z_coords = np.asarray(transformed_points[1,:]).flatten()
```

Basically, the above code works, but when I run it on multiple point clouds from different camera perspectives, they do not magically line up as I would expect.  I can confirm that my inverse homogeneous transform is indeed an inverse to the homogeneous transform constructed directly from rvecs and tvecs; have tried breaking it apart into translation first then rotation, and vice versa; and have seen a non-inverse transformation make everything almost line up from one perspective (but all rotated weirdly from every other perspective)...

Any help appreciated!